# Where is nodeValue for body.childNodes?

Tags: javascript, dom

I runs this Javascript code and get nodeType and nodeName without problem for the body.childNode. However, nodeValue fail to display.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get the node types of the body element's child nodes.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> Whitespace inside elements is considered as text, and text is considered as nodes.</p>
<!-- My personal comment goes here..  -->
<div><strong>Note:</strong> Comments in the document are considered as comment nodes.</div>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var c = document.body.childNodes;
    var txt = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        txt = txt + "notdType: "+ c[i].nodeType + "    NodeName: "+c[i].nodeName+"    NodeValue: "+c[i].nodeValue +"<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Think about it: why is the code iterating through document.body.childNodes instead of finding its nodeValue? Could it be because document.body doesn't have a nodeValue either? Then try to relate body not having a nodeValue, with the nodes that don't have nodeValues. And then, see if you can figure out why those other nodes don't have nodeValues.

Answer (score 0):

Element nodes don't have node values. Instead, they have child nodes of their own.

Comment: I try to use innerText to get value of element node. It seems to be successful. if Element nodes has their child nodes, can I add firstChild after Elements nodes and get the nodeValue?

Comment: What is difference between text Node and Element Node? Is nodeValue only applied to text Node?